# Send data to the browser while waiting (Python)

Tags: python

I have the following code

```
print "Starting stage 1<br>"

# Something that takes about 5 seconds
time.sleep(5)

print "Stage 1 complete"
```

I view the script with my browser as it's part of a web-app, the problem is that it's displaying all of it together. I want it to display first the starting message before it starts and then add the completion message after it's complete.

What do I use to push information to the browser in this fashion?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try flush the output after the first print using sys.stdout.[flush()](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#file.flush)

Comment: Note that this only works so long as your web server isn't buffering output.

Comment: mod_deflate (gzip) is your most likely bet for buffering problems. An alternative to consider is writing an HTML file with a refresh statement or using AJAX to get your done-o-dial effect going on.